# Как разбить число на несколько частей?

Tags: python

Пример:
Если число `1500000`
То в список должен выглядеть так:

```
[1000000, 500000]
```

Если число например 4,3 млн, то так (входное число может быть любым):

```
[1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 1000000, 300000]
```

Comment: А может, деление поможет?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: Покажите ваш пример, это упростит помощь. А так, можно сделать деление на `1_000_000`, чтобы узнать сколько раз встречается число, а после остаток от деления (от изначального числа). Аналог без цикла: `num = 4_300_000` `a, b = divmod(num, 1_000_000)` `print([1_000_000] * a + [b])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def million(input_number):
    divised = []
    while input_number != 0:
        if input_number > 1000000:
            input_number = input_number - 1000000
            divised.append(1000000)
        else:
            divised.append(input_number)
            input_number = input_number - input_number
    return divised
```

Comment: `input_number = input_number - 1000000` можно проще: `input_number -= 1000000`, а почему бы это `input_number = input_number - input_number` просто нулю не прировлять? А лучше вместо этого `break` вызвать